# path must be a string or buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile

I'm now learning NodeJS from nodeschool.io and the third exercise is about I/O file.

It's asking me to write a program using a single synchronous filesystem operation to read a file and print the number of newlines to the console (stdout). The full path to the file to read will be provided as the first command-line argument (i.e., process.argv[2]).

The answer for this exercise is similar to mine so I really know where I got wrong. This is my solution:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var contents = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]);
var strs = contents.toString();
var lines = strs.split('/n').length - 1;

console.log(lines);
```

but i got an error:

```
TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:660:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:565:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projects\dmt-node-study\first-io.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
```

Comment: Have you tried to check what `process.argv[2]` actually is?

Comment: I just checked.
 It said undefined. So my problem is process.argv[2], right?
So how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Pass file path while running code like `node  first-io.js D:\\projects\\dmt-node-study\\first-io.js`

Answer (score 0):

**app.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var contents = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]);
var strs = contents.toString();
var lines = strs.split('\n').length - 1;
console.log(lines);
```

**Running the code from command line**

```
>node app test.txt
```

Considering text file is in your project root directory.